# Why is this j considered an undeclared identifier when it's declared

Tags: c

The `j` in the printing statement is considered an undeclared identifier, how do I fix this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        switch(grid[i][j]){
            case '.':
                colourChange(WHITE);
                break;
            case 'P':
                colourChange(YELLOW);
                break;
            case 'G':
                colourChange(PINK);
                break;
            case 'W':
                colourChange(BLUE);
                break;}
        printf("%c  ", grid[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I declared it in the `for` loop, but it gave an error. Also if I comment out the full `switch` statement it works.

Comment: Fix your indenting and it should be obvious.  You're using `j` outside the block where it's valid.

Comment: it's declared within the scope of the forloop, but you used it outside that scope.

Comment: Don't tag with irrelevant languages. Removed one tag at "random". Fix it if I removed the wrong one.

Comment: C, C++ and C# are not the same thing just be because they all start with *C*, any more than a cat, a car, and a carrot are the same. Use only tags that are actually applicable to your question. Tag spamming is a quick way to get your question closed. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and should not be abused.

Comment: This is why I recommend that *both* `{` and `}` always go on a separate line.  It makes problems like this much easier to spot.

Answer (score 6):

The body of the inner `for` loop is *just* the `switch` statement, so the call to `printf` that follows is outside of the inner loop.

Always use braces:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        switch(grid[i][j]) {
            case '.':
                colourChange(WHITE);
                break;
            case 'P':
                colourChange(YELLOW);
                break;
            case 'G':
                colourChange(PINK);
                break;
            case 'W':
                colourChange(BLUE);
                break;
        }
        printf("%c  ", grid[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Always indent properly, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your second `for` statement. Since it has no curly braces, it assumes the next statement corresponds to its body. Your following `printf("%c  ", grid[i][j]);` assumes that there is no `j` to take into account and is not recognized. A fixed solution may be:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        switch(grid[i][j]) {
            case '.':
                colourChange(WHITE);
                break;
            case 'P':
                colourChange(YELLOW);
                break;
            case 'G':
                colourChange(PINK);
                break;
            case 'W':
                colourChange(BLUE);
                break;
        }
        printf("%c  ", grid[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```